# Centralizing a floating element

Tags: css, css-float, center

My "div" element have a relative width, it isn't absolute so I can't use exact numbers to centralize. A nice solution is to use "display: inline-block":

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#myDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

But this element NEEDS to float, I tried this:

```
#myDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

And this:

```
#myDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Without any success, can somebody help me ?

Thanks

Comment: I see no width, not even a *relative* one. If you declare an element as `float` you **always** have to specify a width.

Comment: I dont think you need width for some element to float... Its just that if you want to float several elements(li's for example) then it would be wise to put a width for every element so you can control that floating. If you dont have width what can happen is that all those inner(floated) elements have combined width larger then parent container width, then last floated element will float below 1st element... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#myDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center any block element with this css:

```
margin:auto;
width: some fixed value;
```

So elment need to have fixed width, in order to be centerd like this.